# Building a Docker file

Tags: python-2.7, docker, dockerfile, xgboost

I am trying to reproduce my development environment in a docker image. I am able to get simple dependencies met such as python+a couple standard packages, largely through the builds from docker hub. But when it comes to installing xgboost or pandas I am having great difficulty.

After looking into the error messages it looked like I had the wrong version of g++ installed. The build had 4.7, but xgboost requires 4.9+. As I tried to update g++ I kept running into a wall where I couldn't update g++ because I needed another package (apt-add-repository), but to install that package I needed another (apt-utils) etc.

Does anyone have any general advice with setting up a Docker image or for this specific problem of upgrading the g++.

Here is the Docker file:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda
MAINTAINER maintainer

RUN apt-get install -y g++-4.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One test would be to start from a [gcc:4.9 image](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc/) ([which uses wheezy](https://github.com/docker-library/gcc/blob/5e3781575c04f31812375822f4f28fbb39da5dc3/4.9/Dockerfile)), and try to add what [anaconda Dockerfile does](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/blob/master/anaconda/Dockerfile).

That way, you start from an image with the right gcc.

Comment: Starting with a container which had the difficult dependencies met, it was straightforward to get the simple dependencies working. Thanks VonC.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure your source list is up-to-date. The line with RUN command in the dockerfile should be

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++
```

Comment: If I don't update my sources list it will install g++4.7. To update my source list I need to use apt-add-repository, but to install that I need apt-utils, etc.